# Resources to help learn Windows kernel development in an operating systems class?

Tags: windows, kernel

I am currently in an university operating system class and we are working on the windows kernel, more precisely  WRK, the windows research kernel, for our projects. WRK is based off of win2k3 server.

I am however having a real hard time dredging up resources to help learn the basics of OS development, Windows kernel development and just generally getting around the Windows API.

We are using the book *Microsoft Internals* by Russinovich but I was wondering if any of you had some great resources to recommend to me, whether book, online guides or some old class notes. Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft gives access to their kernel to universities now?

Comment: We are working on the WRK - windows research kernel. It is based off of win2k3 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What specifically are you looking for? Online resources? For that, [OSROnline](http://www.osronline.com/) is one of the better websites. Alot of kernel development knowledge is found in the MS and the OSR Mailing lists, that's another place to check that might be better than Stack overflow.

Specifically books, there is the [Programming WDM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735618038),[Developing drivers with KMDF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623740) and [Advance Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460). The last specifically will not teach you so much about the kernel and more how to navigate inside it, something you will do quite often if you are writing drivers or researching parts of it.

In order to write drivers, the easiest way is probably to take Windows Driver samples and hack at them, stare the results with windbg and learn more.

Answer (score 2):

microsoft kernel dev? that's just weird. what university are you at?

one of the most interesting things about kernels, in my opinion, is the scheduler algorithms. I'd recommend you check that out.

I can't imagine where you'd start looking for windows stuff though. I did it with the linux kernel and there's a LOT of resources (of course).

http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html

Comment: ah, cleared up with your other comment (wrk). I still think the scheduler is the most complex and interesting part of any kernel, by far, so I recommend you look up how the wrk handles that.

Answer (score 2):

The third edition of Tanenbaum's [Modern Operating Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639) has a chapter devoted to the Vista kernel. I haven't looked into that chapter (I only read the Linux one), but as far as big-picture stuff, it's fantastic. I'm not sure what level of detail you're looking for, but that might be a good resource to check out.

Comment: This seems like it might help slightly but I will still be looking for more things :/. Thanks though!